# Answer to a closed question

Tags: support, answers, closed-questions, self-answer

I'm interested in the following question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1851713/84976
and I'd like to provide an answer. 
The problem is that the question has been closed (maybe before the last edit it wasn't clear). 
What can I do? Should do I ask the question newly by myself?

Comment: Since this particular question was posted just a few hours ago, maybe you could leave some time for the OP - it is possible he will improve the question and that will lead to reopening. In fact, you can help the OP - if you post some kind of hint in a comment, perhaps they will be able to find at least partial solution - which is one of the possibilities how to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). (Notice that four users chose *missing context* as the close reason.)

Answer (score 4):

First: The question was closed for lack of context and I completely agree with this closure. Part of the purpose of closing questions is to prevent more answers to be added.

That said, I agree with the comment by Martin Sleziak above. I would say to leave it as is for some time. Give the OP an opportunity to add context to the question. If this doesn't happen within a day or two, I would find it completely fine to repost the question **[with context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)**. I suggest adding a link to the closed question and explain your reasoning for your interest in the question. While many of us don't like questions without context, there is still some discussion on what exactly constitutes context. IMO you can in this specific case provide context by simply explaining where the question comes from and why you find the question interesting. Please also say in the question that you plan to answer the question yourself. (You can post the answer [at the same time](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/recently-rolled-out-se-encyclopedia-feature) you post the question.) That way people will know that you aren't just trying to get someone to do your homework.

Comment: Re: *Please also say in the question that you plan to answer the question yourself.* There is also a possibility to post a question and the answer at the same time, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/recently-rolled-out-se-encyclopedia-feature).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: And even if you do answer it at the same time, I would still recommend mentioning in the question that you are doing this.

Comment: @Thomas Why? Imagine someone two years from now having the same question. They type some keywords in a search engine and they find the question. It turns out the question was self-answered. Do they care whatsoever so long as the answer is good? Nope. If anybody has any doubt that the OP is trying to get people to do their homework (something largely irrelevant if the question is of good enough quality), then they can simply see that the asker and the answerer are the same user.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I doubt that most people look at who answers the questions. I rarely look at who answered the question before I decide what to do. Anyway, with the hostility towards homework questions and questions without context, I think this *might* be a small thing that could help cause less friction. It is just a short sentence that one can add. You are, of course, free to disagree.